# Clourescript: converting array access

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

## Problem

I am trying to convert the following piece of code: https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/blob/gh-pages/tutorial/glUtils.js#L13-L15

## The JavaScript code is:

```
Matrix.Translation = function (v)
{
  // ignore length 2 case for simplicty

  if (v.elements.length == 3) {
    var r = Matrix.I(4);
    r.elements[0][3] = v.elements[0];
    r.elements[1][3] = v.elements[1];
    r.elements[2][3] = v.elements[2];
    return r;
  }

  throw "Invalid length for Translation";
}
```

## Now, I can rewrite it cljs as follows:

```
(defn translation [x y z]
  (let [r (. js/Matrix I 4)]
     r[0][3] = x ;; how do I write this?
     r[1][3] = y ;; how do I write this?
     r[2][3] = z ;; how do I write this?
  ))
```

## Question

However, how do I write r[0][3] in cljs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`aget`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/#aget) and `aset` to work with Javascript arrays:

```
(def arr (array (array "a1" "a2") (array "b1" "b2") (array "c1" "c2")))
```

It creates following nested array:

```
#js [#js ["a1" "a2"] #js ["b1" "b2"] #js ["c1" "c2"]]
```

You can access nested elements with `aget`:

```
(aget arr 1 0)
;; => "b1"
```

And update with `aset`:

```
(aset arr 1 0 "newb1")
```

updates `arr` to:

```
#js [#js ["a1" "a2"] #js ["newb1" "b2"] #js ["c1" "c2"]]
```

You might want to take a look at other functions related to Javascript arrays: [`alength`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/#alength), [`array`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/#array), [`make-array`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/#make-array), [`array?`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/#arrayQMARK).